# Crystal report how to down then across column

Tags: crystal-reports

[Crystal report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U6qER.png)

How to separate my column in two without separating my groups

Comment: Show some code to detail what you've already tried, SO is not a code writing service.

Comment: show your expected output